# How to show a database colum data on my php script?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script made by me that can change a database info by taking db name,user,pass and host. Now I want to show a database column info to my php script.
Now how can i do that here is my main db.php script i didn't put the html from script cause i don't think it's necessary.

I have code this but it's showing a error like that

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/abc/public_html/db.php on line 56
```

Here is my db.php

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAwADAPcAAAAAAABCAP///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////ywAAAAAAwADAAAICQADABhIcGBAAAA7');
font-family: Tahoma;text-align: center;color: green;
}
img{opacity:0.75; filter:alpha(opacity=75);}

.field_set{
 border-color:#4AB825;
}

</style>

<?php

// escape received values

$dbusr = $_POST['usr'];
$dbpsw = $_POST['psw'];
$dbhost = $_POST['host'];
$dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
$admusr = $_POST['admusr'];
$prfx = $_POST['prfx'];
$admpsw = md5($_POST['admpsw']);


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbusr, $dbpsw);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Database Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Database Connected successfully";
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$dbname");


// use them in query
$sql = "UPDATE ".$prfx."_users SET user_login='".$admusr."',user_pass='".$admpsw."'  WHERE id=1";




if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br><br>Record updated successfully</br></br>Go to your login page <br><br>ex: www.site.com/wp-admin<br><br>and login with your given id and pass";
} else {
    echo "<br>Error updating record:" . $conn->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT guid FROM".$prfx."_posts;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Site:" . $row["guid"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Look at the colour codeing

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT guid FROM".$prfx."_posts;
```

Should be

```
$sql = "SELECT guid FROM".$prfx."_posts";
```

You were missing the closing "

As Dagon said in his comment, In most editors code is shown with color coding, and you can usually see if a " or ' is missing it's closing tag because the color will be off.

**UPDATE**

Missing space between FROM and $prfx, use below:

```
$sql = "SELECT guid FROM ".$prfx."_posts";
```

Comment: I fix that what u said but now it's not showing error but it's don't showing guid column data from database on my screen. It's show a sql error :(                                                                                       Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/localhost/public_html/db.php on line 53
0 results

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/localhost/public_html/db.php on line 53
0 results

Comment: It's Working fine now :) I have 3 row on that column it's show all but I want to show only one data how can i do this @Epodax

Comment: That depends on which of the three you want to display, if it's the first then you can use `LIMIT 1` otherwise you can use `WHERE field = 'value'` or use a if clause to check the value and echo the desired result :) don't forget to mark your question as solved

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a " at the end of line try replace this.

```
$sql = "SELECT guid FROM".$prfx."_posts";
```

Whenever you get this error it means that you are missing a closing double quote on that line which is mentioned on the error.

Comment: I fix that what u said but now it's not showing error but it's don't showing guid column data from database on my screen. It's show a sql error :(

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
$sql = "SELECT guid FROM".$prfx."_posts;
```

to this,

```
$sql = "SELECT guid FROM".$prfx."_posts";
```

Comment: I fix that what u said but now it's not showing error but it's don't showing guid column data from database on my screen. It's show a sql error :(

Comment: Hope @Epodax 's answer solved your problem. Please mark his answer as verified.